# MySQL: Select rows with values nearest but greater than a given value

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, I'm struggling here. I have a MySQL table of unsorted values that is structured about like this:

```
ID     Size
-----  -----
1      12
2      10
3      1
4      0
5      8
6      9
7      6
8      2
9      9
10     4
```

What I'd like to do is given a size (e.g. size = 5) extract the next bigger rows (and the next smaller eventually).

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Size > 5 ORDER BY Size DESC LIMIT 2
```

But that gives me:

```
ID     Size
-----  -----
1      12
2      10
```

but what I want is

```
ID     Size
-----  -----
7      6
5      8
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using PHP to access the table if that makes a difference.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using DESC that fetching result in descending . you should use ASC that will fetch results in ascending.

**Example-**

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Size > 5 ORDER BY Size ASC LIMIT 2
```

**EDITED**

You need to first fetch in descending order then you need to again order by ascending.

**Example-**

```
  SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Size > 5 ORDER BY Size DESC ) AS r
ORDER BY r.Size ASC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Yes, of course! Thanks! That grabs the correct rows, but I'd also like them to appear in descending order. Is there a way to do that too?

Comment: if you want to do in php you can use array_reverse and if you want to do in mysql then see my udpated answer.

Comment: Yes! That basically works, but I ended up doing this:    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Size > 5 ORDER BY Size ASC LIMIT 2) AS r
ORDER BY r.Size DESC  Also, I'm too new to +1, so I'll just have to say thanks here.

Answer (score 1):

You could select the rows having size greater 5 as a sub-query and select first two rows from the result set of the sub-query.

**Query**

```
select t.* from(
  select * from your_table_name
  where size > 5
)t
order by t.size asc limit 2;
```

**[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82fe41/2)**

Answer (score 0):

You should use ASC, not DESC in the ORDER BY clause